# Move topSearch to nav container using local.xml

Tags: xml, magento, layout

How can I move the topSearch block to inside "nav-container" div, using local.xml?

What I did:

1) used unsetChild method to remove from header: OK

2) added in 'default' handle of local.xml

```
        <reference name="top.menu"> 
        <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/> 
    </reference>
```

The topSearch appeared directly under the "nav-container" div. I tried to include in topmenu.phtml

```
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
```

But nothing happens :(

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I just had the same problem. I posted my solution: [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/5171/#t449130)

hope it works for you..